# Feature extraction for classification of Handwritten digit images

Tags: python, image, classification

I am trying to find some features to write a function that helps to extract features from handwritten digit images for binary classification purposes. I have already tried functions like summing all the pixels in the images and symmetrical features but it doesn't give satisfactory accuracy. Anyone who has a good function for extraction of features for my data that help my model perform well is much appreciated please help...